# Clock form and derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, differential-forms

Consider $X,Y$ two smooth vector fields of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and
the set $C=\{z\in \mathbb{R}^2;\, det(X,Y)(z)\neq 0\}$.

On the set $C$, we define the form $\alpha$ by :

- $
  \alpha(X)=1,\quad \alpha(Y)=0.
  $
- Given a trajectory $z(\cdot)$ 
  solution on $[0,T]$ of the system
  $$
  \dot z(t) = X(z(t)) + u(t)\,Y(z(t))
  $$
  where $u$ is a given function and such that $z(.)\in C$,
  we define:
  $$
  \int_{z(\cdot)} \alpha = T.
  $$

On which set do we have $d\alpha=0$ ?

Comment: The form $\alpha$ is well-defined the minute you specify its values at $X$ and $Y$. What is the purpose of the rest of the post?

Comment: apparently we can have a general picture of the kernel of $d\alpha$ which is the set where $Y,[X,Y]$ are collinear... but I can't see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the intrinsic expression for the exterior derivative, we have $$d\alpha(X,Y)=X(\alpha(Y))-Y(\alpha(X))-\alpha([X,Y])=-\alpha([X,Y]).$$ So, $\alpha$ is closed at every point where $\alpha([X,Y])=0$. But, by construction, the kernel of $\alpha$ at a point $p$ is the line spanned by $Y(p)$. Hence, $d\alpha$ vanishes at $p$ if and only if $Y$ and $[X,Y]$ are colinear at $p$.